# How do I figure out the parameters for a stored procedure I was not told how to run

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently taking an on-line course for Database administration. The question I am stuck on is below. I have gone through the entire lesson and have not found the answer, I've also looked around here and other websites. With no avail. So I was wondering if someone could help me out with this question?

Question:
Suppose your co-worker creates a stored procedure for you, but doesn't tell you how to run it. How can you figure out which parameters the procedure uses?

Comment: You can go and ask him the in and out parameters. That's one way for sure.!!!

Comment: Genetic algorithms, obviously. You pass random things until something works. </sarcasm>

Comment: This wasn't too hard to find: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/listing-stored-procedures-in-mysql-database.aspx

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

execute this query below,

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName;
```

it will show you the parameters and the entire procedure how it was created.